# How to Remove URL Parameter with Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-parameters

I've been looking for an efficient way to do this but haven't been able to find it, basically what I need is that given this url for example:

```
https://localhost/p/sampel.html?linkgo=&redir=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20v
```

Become

```
https://localhost/p/sampel.html?aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20v
```

I'd like to be able to remove the URL in the `linkgo=&redir=` parameter using javascript or jquery, is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible, please show us what you have tried. Also if you search your title on google then you can find many answers

Comment: You can just replace it like so. Do you want to loose all query names, or just those two do you also have other usecases? Why? `"https://localhost/p/sampel.html?linkgo=&redir=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20v".replace('linkgo=&redir=', '')`